# Placement of a year in mid-sentence

Tags: sentence-structure, time

Can I use 2017 in the middle of the sentence? For example:

> The platform was launched in 2017, with an extensive support of our venture fund.

Comment: Could you provide more detail about what makes you think this would or wouldn't be okay? As it is, this isn't a very good SE question, because the only answer seems to be "sure, why not?"

Comment: Yes.  Is there some rule you've been taught that says you can only put the year certain places in a sentence?

Comment: It seems incorrect because it is placed in the middle of the sentence, while I thought it must be at the beginning or the end. I can't name any exact rule; I was just doubting.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is YES, you can use a year in the middle of a sentence, or anywhere in a sentence for that matter!

There are various "rules" for written English regarding the expression of numbers as words or numerals (ie "one" or "1"). I have heard it said that numbers 1 to 9 should be expressed as words when used in a sentence, so perhaps this is why you are questioning your use of a number in a sentence. Such rules do not govern the English language as a whole but may be enforced in certain professions, for example among journalists.

Generally speaking, the only expectation for using numbers in written English is that you are *consistent* throughout your piece - that is if you use numerals once, continue to do so throughout the same piece of writing.

However, in your specific example of writing the *year* - this is almost always expressed using numerals, so no such rules would apply. Writing the year as *twenty-seventeen* or even *two thousand and seventeen* would be extremely difficult to read and lead to inaccuracies.